# Multiple Post request (Axios | React)

Tags: javascript, api, reactjs, redux, axios

How do i call multiple API from axios? i need to call 2 different API to show some data in my front-end.

here's my code

> Actions/index.js

```
export function userAuth() {

    return (dispatch, getState) => {
      axios.post('url', {
        usuario: 'test',
        password: 'test'
      })
      .then((response) => {
        // console.log(response.data);
        dispatch( { type: USER_AUTH, payload: response.data } )
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
    }
}

export function userLog() {

    return (dispatch, getState) => {
      axios.post('url', {
        clientId: '1',
        sensor: 'test',
        dateStart: '2016-09-03 00:00:00"',
        dateEnd: '2016-09-03 23:59:59'

      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
        dispatch( { type: USER_LOG, payload: response.data } )
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
    }
}

axios.all([userAuth(), userLog()])
  .then(axios.spread(function (acct, perms) {
    console.log(userLog());
  }))
```

> Reducer/userlog.js

```
export function userLog(state = initialState, action) {

    switch (action.type) {
        case USER_LOG:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {list: action.payload})
        default:
            return state
    }

}
```

but the second console.log() in my api call, doesnt print anything, what im missing? or what im doing wrong?...

And the 2d question is, after done all, how do i can edit the body of my API call? i need a dynamic body, i mean

1 API => response an array with some text.

2 API => the body will be changed foreach array from (1 API)?

**

Comment: did you figure out the solution?

Comment: No dude, i just left that project.